# MDI Child Forms C#

Tags: c#, mdichild, mdiparent

How do you check for a close event for an MDI child form when clicking the "X" button and let the parent form know that it has closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply listen to the FormClosed event in the MDI.

```
var childForm = new ChildForm();
childForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form_FormClosed);
childForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the form FormClosing event you can do

```
TheMainForm form = (TheMainForm)this.MdiParent()
form.AlertMe( this );
```

Comment: There's no .AlertMe() method in C# that I can find no an MDiParent method, only a property.

Comment: You would create your own, make it public

Answer (score 0):

Attach a closed event to the childform from within the mainForm

```
Form mdiChild = new Form();
mdiChild.MdiParent = this;
mdiChild.Closed += (s, e) => { //... };
mdiChild.Show();
```

didn't check the code but should not be that hard

Answer (score 0):

well, The below code shows how parent form recognises whether the child form has been closed or not and it can also recognises that is there any new  child form is added to that parent form..

```
private List<Form> ChildFormList = new List<Form>();

private void MyForm_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form f = this.ActiveMdiChild;

   if (f == null)
   {
    //the last child form was just closed
    return;
   }

   if (!ChildFormList.Contains(f))
   {
      //a new child form was created
      ChildFormList.Add(f);
      f.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ChildFormClosed); // here the parent form knows that that child form has been closed or not
  }
  else
  {
    //activated existing form
  }
}
private void ChildFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   //a child form was closed
    Form f = (Form)sender;
    ChildFormList.Remove(f);
}
```